# Haskell (Parsing) code can't understand how it works

Tags: parsing, haskell

```
openBr = char '['
closeBr = char ']'
openPn = char '('
closePn = char ')'
star = char '*'

myParser =
    (many1 star >>=
        \vs -> myParser >>=
            \x -> return (x+length vs)
    ) +++
        (openBr >>
            myParser >>=
                \c -> closeBr >>
                    myParser >>=
                        \d -> return (c+d)
        ) +++
            (openPn >>
                myParser >>=
                    \c -> closePn >>
                        myParser >>=
                            \d -> return (c+d)
            ) +++
                return 0
```

```hs
parse myParser "*(***[*(**)]*)*" 
-- outputs ([9,""])
parse myParser "*(***[*(**]*)*"
-- outputs ([1, "(***[*(**]*)*"])
```

when there is a matching bracket and parentheses it returns the number of stars however it returns like the second output. I don't understand how the code works. Can someone explain it for me?

Comment: It stopped after the first star, because the rest of the string does not match the grammar defined by the parser.

Comment: how about "parse myParser "*(***[*(**)]*)*" " isn't myParser is recursively calling the function again?

Comment: @sunny Is there a reason you haven't used `do` notation? It would make your code much clearer.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, when writing monadic Haskell code like this, It is idiomatic to use [`do` notation](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/do_notation). This reduces noise and makes your intention clearer.

Rewritten using `do` notation, your parser would look like this:

```hs
myParser =
    -- run of stars
    (do
        vs <- many1 star
        x  <- myParser
        return (x+length vs)
    ) +++
    -- brackets
        (do
            openBr
            c <- myParser
            closeBr
            d <- myParser
            return (c+d)
        ) +++
    -- parentheses
            (do
                openPn
                c <- myParser
                closePn
                d <- myParser
                return (c+d)
            ) +++
    -- fail
                return 0
```

Now, when you parse the second example, the parser correctly parses the first star, and tots the total up to 1. It then sees the open bracket, so it chooses the bracket choice.

The brackets are not balanced however, so the bracket parser fails, despite being able to parse a some of the characters following the open bracket. This causes the failure to bubble upward and fail the overall parse. When this happens, the `parse` function returns the return value accumulated to date, i.e. the number of stars before the failure, as well as the remainder of the string which failed to parse.

What you want to happen in this situation is for the parse to fail and return `0`. Since your parsing library doesn't automatically backtrack, you'll need to explicitly enable backtracking by wrapping the subparsers in your library's equivalent of the `try` combinator.

Happy Haskelling!